# Is it safe to transmute::<&'a Arc<T>, &'a Weak<T>>(…)?

Tags: rust, unsafe

Is it safe to [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/fn.transmute.html) a shared reference `&` to a strong [`Arc<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) into a shared reference `&` to a [`Weak<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Weak.html)?

To ask another way: is the following safe function [sound](https://docs.rs/dtolnay/latest/dtolnay/macro._03__soundness_bugs.html#soundness), or is it a vulnerability waiting to happen?

```rust
pub fn as_weak<'a, T>(strong: &'a Arc<T>) -> &'a Weak<T> {
    unsafe { transmute::<&'a Arc<T>, &'a Weak<T>>(strong) }
}
```

##### Why I want to do this

We have an existing function that returns a `&Weak<T>`. The internal data structure has changed a bit, and I now have an `Arc<T>` where I previously had a `Weak<T>`, but I need to maintain semver compatibility with this function's interface. I'd rather avoid needing to stash an actual `Weak<T>` copy just for the sake of this function if I don't need to.

##### Why I hope this is safe

The underlying memory representations of `Arc<T>` and `Weak<T>` are the same: a not-null pointer (or pointer-like value for [`Weak::new()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Weak.html#method.new)) to an internal [`ArcInner`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#:%7E:text=struct%20ArcInner) struct, which contains the strong and weak reference counts and the inner `T` value.

`Arc<T>` also contains a `PhantomData<T>`, but my understanding is that if that changes anything, it would only apply on drop, which isn't relevant for the case here as we're only transmuting a shared reference, not an owned value.

The operations that an `Arc<T>` will perform on its inner pointer are presumably a superset of those that may be performed by a `Weak<T>`, since they have the same representation but `Arc` carries a guarantee that the inner `T` value is still alive, while `Weak` does not.

Given these facts, it seems to me like nothing could go wrong. However, I haven't written much `unsafe` code before, and never for a production case like this. I'm not confident that I fully understand the possible issues. Is this transmutation safe and sound, or are are there other factors that need to be considered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not sound.

Neither `Arc` nor `Weak` has a `#[repr]` forcing a particular layout, therefore they are both `#[repr(Rust)]` by default.  According to [the Rustonomicon section about `repr(Rust)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/repr-rust.html):

> ```
> struct A {
>     a: i32,
>     b: u64,
> }
>
> struct B {
>     a: i32,
>     b: u64,
> }
> ```
>
> Rust *does* guarantee that two instances of A have their data laid out in exactly the same way. However Rust *does not* currently guarantee that an instance of A has the same field ordering or padding as an instance of B.

You cannot therefore assume that `Arc<T>` and `Weak<T>` have the same layout.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's a bummer, but it makes sense. I've gone and [posted my first thread on rust-internals](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/marking-arc-rc-weak-as-repr-transparent/17171?u=jeremybanks) to see if folks might be interested in adding the necessary `#[repr(transparent)]`s to enable this.

Comment: I got some informative feedback on IRLO. Apparently, even if the `Arc`/`Rc`/`Weak` types were marked as `#[repr(transparent)]`, it still wouldn't be appropriate to transmute them because the representation is still considered private as long as the fields are private. So this conversion can only be safely performed by the standard library itself. Let's see what the Rust team thinks of it: [Rust PR #100472: Add function Arc/Rc::as_weak(…) to convert &Arc/Rc to &Weak](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/100472)